# How to maintain fixed layout even if removing any HTML DOM element

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I need a help regarding HTML design using bootstrap.
Am using tabs in the design and if am removing any element using ngIf (Angular code), the design is
getting adjusted accordingly, which is quite obvious.

But, I want the design to stay fixed, even if I remove any element.
I have also used [hidden] instead of "ngIf" and still its not working.

Can anyone please help me?

Below is my html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-5-12">
   <div id="SecCorrTxtBox" class="row"
        *ngIf ="(!isSecCorrelationCoeffHidden && isSecondaryCorrelationChecked)">
      <label class="col-lg-3-12 control-label">Coefficients</label>
      <div class="col-lg-3-12 remove-left-padding">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="coeffs2"
                 [(ngModel)]="secondaryCoeffParameter1"
                 min="0" step="1">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can show your css code !!

Comment: @MMezlini - I have not used my custom css. All are bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add dynamic CSS using [ngStyle] or [ngClass] that has property visibility: hidden. Visibility hidden still takes up space.

Answer (score 0):

You want your design to stay, you must fixed it when the bloc is empty.
The `span` will be displayed when your condition is false

```
<div class="col-lg-5-12">
   <span *ngIf ="!(!isSecCorrelationCoeffHidden && isSecondaryCorrelationChecked)"> &nbsp; </span>
   <div id="SecCorrTxtBox" class="row"
        *ngIf ="(!isSecCorrelationCoeffHidden && isSecondaryCorrelationChecked)">
      <label class="col-lg-3-12 control-label">Coefficients</label>
      <div class="col-lg-3-12 remove-left-padding">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="coeffs2"
                 [(ngModel)]="secondaryCoeffParameter1"
                 min="0" step="1">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you asking for ?

Comment: Hi @MMezlini, No, that's not what I am looking for. I want to display the whole div if the condition is false. I tried using [hidden] in Angular but its the same.
[style.visibility] is working what I want but the problem is:
In a DIV there r a group of 3 textboxes and a checkbox. I want to display any of those depending upon condition. So, I put *ngIf. But since the whole DOM element is getting removed the design is getting adjusted accordingly.

I want the main DIV to occupy the space and stay fixed. The group of textboxes or the checkbox will be displayed depending upon condition.